# Drawing contours with bounded rectangles on existing image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

My objective is to pick up an image, separate out the curves/contours that have a grayscale threshold below a local number (say 3), and then have rectangles around them, while writing this back onto the original image - as a way of detecting cracks on a grayscale image. Below is what I have come up with - by seeing tutorials online.

```
# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load an color image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('chest-ct-lungs.jpg',0)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,3,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Detect the contours in the image
image, contours =         
cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Draw all the contours
all_contour_img = cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imwrite('all_contour_img.png',all_contour_img)

# Use bounding rectangles
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours)
cv2.rectangle(all_contour_img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

# Draw over original image
imwrite(uint8(double(img)+all_contour_img), 'output.png');
```

However, I am getting this as the output when I run it using python IDLE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\com\Desktop\python.py", line 17, in <module>
     all_contour_img = cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'image'
```

Any inputs on where I am going wrong, as well as better practices of writing the above code - I'm a beginner.

I want this to happen :

[image]

Comment: `image, contours = cv2.findContours(....)` -- read the documentation (specific to the version of OpenCV you use -- i guess either 2.4 or 4.x), you misnamed/misinterpreted the result values. The first one isn't an image, and the second one isn't contours. As a result, you're trying to use a list of contours as if it was an image and draw on it... that obviously won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the version of OpenCV you are using, cv2.findContours() will return a list of contours and some other stuff. All that you want is the list of contours. You can just ignore the other stuff and clean up your code by assigning those unused variables to an `_`.

`cv2.findContours` returns a **LIST** of contours. This is like a list of shapes. If you want to draw a `bounding rectangle` around each shape, you need to iterate through the list of contours.

```
# Import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load an color image in grayscale, threshold
img = cv2.imread('/home/stephen/Desktop/test.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,3,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Detect the contours in the image
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Draw all the contours
img = cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 1)

# Iterate through all the contours
for contour in contours:
    # Find bounding rectangles
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    # Draw the rectangle
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,0),1)

# Write the image
cv2.imwrite('/home/stephen/Desktop/lines.png', img);
```

[image: test image][image: processed image]