# python opencv extract multiple images in png spritesheet

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, sprite-sheet

I have some spritesheets that are packed with multiple images (with different size) inside separated with transparent spcae.

I want to extract individual images and save them.
So far i was able to create this abstraction in red and yellow.

I don't know how to proceed in finding the bounding boxes of all those.

If you can point me to some numpy or opencv methods that can help.

[image]

Comment: Post a real image example. Segregating each yellow region from the red is trivial. It is the extraction of the binary image from a real image that may be the hard part. With what you have, just threshold on color (cv2.inRange) and then get contours and their bounding boxes.

Comment: [This should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55362501/drawing-contours-with-bounded-rectangles-on-existing-image)